# Use of generics in a final method that returns a value of the same type of its object

Tags: java, hierarchy, class-hierarchy, generics

Consider the following immutable classes:

```
A
B extends A
C extends B
D extends C
...
```

Class A has a method called `process` that gets a parameter of type `A`, and then returns a value of the type of the calling object:

```
public class A {

    public final <T extends A> T process(A a) {
        Class clazz = getClass();
        T result = createObjectOfType(clazz);
        return result;
        }
    }

public class B extends A { }

public class C extends B { }
```

This is the (very simple) test code:

```
public void test()
    {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    C c = new C();

    // Returns type A:

    A resultAAA = a.process(a); // Works.
    A resultAAB = a.process(b); // Works.
    A resultAAC = a.process(c); // Works.

    B resultAAA = a.process(a); // Runtime error.
    B resultAAB = a.process(b); // Runtime error.
    B resultAAC = a.process(c); // Runtime error.

    C resultAAA = a.process(a); // Runtime error.
    C resultAAB = a.process(b); // Runtime error.
    C resultAAC = a.process(c); // Runtime error.

    // Returns type B:

    A resultBBA = b.process(a); // Works.
    A resultBBB = b.process(b); // Works.
    A resultBBC = b.process(c); // Works.

    B resultBBA = b.process(a); // Works.
    B resultBBB = b.process(b); // Works.
    B resultBBC = b.process(c); // Works.

    C resultBBA = b.process(a); // Runtime error.
    C resultBBB = b.process(b); // Runtime error.
    C resultBBC = b.process(c); // Runtime error.

    // Returns type C:

    A resultCCA = c.process(a); // Works.
    A resultCCB = c.process(b); // Works.
    A resultCCC = c.process(c); // Works.

    B resultCCA = c.process(a); // Works.
    B resultCCB = c.process(b); // Works.
    B resultCCC = c.process(c); // Works.

    C resultCCA = c.process(a); // Works.
    C resultCCB = c.process(b); // Works.
    C resultCCC = c.process(c); // Works.

    }
```

I want to modify the source code to convert those **runtime** errors into **compile time** errors or warnings, without having to overload or override the `process` method.

However, the **client/test** code must not change (no casts or generic parameters).

**Edit:** There is no real solution to this question. So I accepted the obvious answer about overriding the `process` method. This is what works best for the client code, even though it's a maintenance nightmare. Maybe one day Java type system could be modified so that it would be possible to write "the type of this". Then we could write something like `public final this process(A a)`. See the suggestion in [this page](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2010/10/25/using-builder-pattern-subclasses) (in the comments section) if you're interested.

Comment: The method `process` does not use `a`. Did you mean `a.getClass()`?

Comment: @pbabcdefp No, the OP really means A.getClass(), B.getClass() or C.getClass(), depending on the actual runtime type of the object.

Comment: Just clarifying, by "no generic parameters", do you mean on the method calls in the trst code, or on the classes definitions, or something else?

Comment: @marcg This strangely reminds me of real numbers, integers and naturals... ;) Yours is a tough problem. Have you considered a double-dispatch approach?

Comment: @Magnamag Yes, this is a better way to ask that question, and I linked here from there. About double-dispatch, I guess it is about running different code depending on the object type, but here the code is the same (the internals of the `process` method don't change). I just want to find a way to make the compiler see that `c.process(...)` returns a value of `C` type, for example.

Comment: @Bohemian Generics internally is ok (I am already using them in my class definition BTW), but not in client/test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Java 5, your code is allowed to have co-variant return types for methods that are overridden in subclasses.  What does this mean?

It means that the return type of an overridden method must be a subclass of the original method.  This enables subclasses to return types that are of the appropriate type rather than the parent type.

Say you have a method in A that you want to use in subclass B, but you want it to return a B instance.  Use this pattern:

```
class A {
    public A myMethod() { ... }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override public B myMethod() { ... }
}
```

Class B overrides the method in class A (it can invoke it, if needed, by making a call to super.myMethod()) and returns a B instance.  This is allowed because B is a subtype of A (and in class design language, B -is an- A).

Comment: As I said, I don't want to overload or override the `process` method. I have dozens of classes in the hierarchy, and the method code is the same. So it would be very repetitive. The `process` method should be considered final.

Comment: @marcg It wouldn't be that repetitive. You don't need to write the entire method. All you need is `return (B) super.process(a);`. scottb's answer is the correct one (and it does translate the runtime exceptions into compilation errors).

Comment: If I have 20 classes and 30 methods, then I have to create 600 methods, 570 of which are useless if only the Java type system can achieve something that seems so simple. Maybe the Java type system was developed solely for the `Collection` use case... Anyway, I already knew of the repetitive solution and that's why in my question I specifically stated that I didn't want to override the method.

Comment: However, you are right that I should consider this the correct answer if the perfect solution is indeed impossible. But I guess I will wait some more to see if someone comes up with a breakthrough...

Comment: I believe this is the same problem that arises in respect to the Builder-Pattern. Have a look (the repetitive solution is under the title "A nasty solution"): https://weblogs.java.net/node/642849

Answer (score 2):

Use a self-referencing type:

```
public class A<T extends A<T>>{

    public final T process(A a) {
        Class clazz = getClass();
        T result = createObjectOfType(clazz);
        return result;
    }
}

public class B<T extends B<T>> extends A<T>{ }

public class C extends B<C> { }
```

To avoid generic parameters entirely in the client code, you would have to create a second set of generic classes whose fixed-type implementations are A, B, C etc, like this:

```
public class BaseA<T extends BaseA<T>>{
    public final T process(BaseA a) {
        Class clazz = getClass();
        T result = createObjectOfType(clazz);
        return result;
    }
}
public class A extends BaseA<A> {}

public class BaseB<T extends BaseB<T> extends BaseA<BaseB<T>> {}

public class B extends BaseB<B> {}

public class C extends BaseB<C> {}
```

The problem here is that `b instance A` won't be true, but it may feel close enough that the client code won't care.

Comment: I believe he said he did not want the solution to use generic type parameters.

Comment: The solution may use generic type parameters internally. I just don't want to use them in the client/test code. I don't want to write something like `B<B> = new B<>();` in the client code, for example.

Comment: Based on the information provided so far, this does appear to be the solution.

Comment: This is clever. But, as you noticed, I need `b instance A == true`. Otherwise it breaks the `A resultBBA = b.process(a);` line.

Comment: Btw this is called [*"F-bounded quantification"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification).

Comment: @marcg, erasure (single worst idea ever) is going to get you if you try to combine C is a B is a A with no generic parameters and F-bounded polymorphism.  The reason is that you aren't allowed to implement a generic interface in two different concrete types.

Answer (score 1):

This is an annoying problem. There is no way to express that the return type has the same type as the instance on which the method is called. I would recommend the covariant return types solution of scottb. All you need to do is change the signature of `process` in `A` to be

```
public A process(A a)
```

and then override in each subclass with a one-liner. E.g. in `C`:

```
 @Override
 public C process(A a) { return (C) super.process(a); }
```

If you don't want to do this over and over in every subclass, there is a solution using a **static** method instead.

```
public static <T extends A> T process(T t, A a) { 
    Class<?> clazz = t.getClass();
    return (T) createObjectOfType(clazz);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've found a way to satisfy all your requirements. The trick is to force the compiler to notice that you want to invoke the `process()` method only on instances whose type is equal to or is a subtype of the type returned by `process()`.

To achieve this, I'm using a static helper method. Please read the comments in the code, as they explain the trick being used:

```
public class GenericsNightmare {

    // Should reside in the same package as class A
    public static final class U { // Utils

        private U() {
            // No instances
        }

        public static <T extends A> T process(T target, A a) {
            // Here is enforced that returned type T
            // matches the instance type on which the method
            // is called, because it's being invoked on an
            // argument whose type is T as well
            return target.process(a);
        }

        // TODO Other 29 one-liner methods in a similar fashion ;)
    }

    // Should reside in the same package as class U
    public static class A {

        // Don't make this method public unless
        // you want runtime errors instead of
        // compilationn errors! 
        // In other words, this is to avoid the
        // well-known "heap pollution" problem
        final <T extends A> T process(A a) {
            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                // The cast below is safe because we're being called
                // from within the static method of the utility class
                // (i.e. we already know we are of type T)
                Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) this.getClass();
                T result = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {
    }

    public static class C extends B {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();

        // Returns type A:

        // Use the static helper method to 
        // call the process() method, oh yes ;)

        A resultAAA = U.process(a, a); // Compiles
        A resultAAB = U.process(a, b); // Compiles
        A resultAAC = U.process(a, c); // Compiles

        B resultBAA = U.process(a, a); // Compilation error
        B resultBAB = U.process(a, b); // Compilation error
        B resultBAC = U.process(a, c); // Compilation error

        C resultCAA = U.process(a, a); // Compilation error
        C resultCAB = U.process(a, b); // Compilation error
        C resultCAC = U.process(a, c); // Compilation error

        // Returns type B:

        A resultABA = U.process(b, a); // Compiles
        A resultABB = U.process(b, b); // Compiles
        A resultABC = U.process(b, c); // Compiles

        B resultBBA = U.process(b, a); // Compiles
        B resultBBB = U.process(b, b); // Compiles
        B resultBBC = U.process(b, c); // Compiles

        C resultCBA = U.process(b, a); // Compilation error
        C resultCBB = U.process(b, b); // Compilation error
        C resultCBC = U.process(b, c); // Compilation error

        // Returns type C:

        A resultACA = U.process(c, a); // Compiles
        A resultACB = U.process(c, b); // Compiles
        A resultACC = U.process(c, c); // Compiles

        B resultBCA = U.process(c, a); // Compiles
        B resultBCB = U.process(c, b); // Compiles
        B resultBCC = U.process(c, c); // Compiles

        C resultCCA = U.process(c, a); // Compiles
        C resultCCB = U.process(c, b); // Compiles
        C resultCCC = U.process(c, c); // Compiles

    }
}
```

As you see, classes `A`, `B` and `C` are left untouched, with neither generic type params nor overriden methods. Besides, you are getting compilation errors instead of runtime errors.

The trade-off is that you have to use the static helper method from your client code. However, you don't need to use generic type parameters or casts.

If you don't like or can't take this approach, you could use this other trick (equally hacky, though more error-prone), which doesn't require a static helper method:

1. In `A`, change `process()` signature to:

   ```
   public <T extends A> T process(T self, A a)
   ```
2. In your client, change invocations to:

   ```
   A resultAAA = instance.process(instance, a);
   ```

   where the first argument must be the same reference on which the method is being invoked.

Comment: Yes. But I don't want to use static methods. I would like to have a solution without modifying my client/test code.

Comment: @marcg and what about the alternative `A resultAAA = a.process(a, a);`?

Comment: @marcg I thought that you were open to change the signature: "Yes, I want to modify the signature, the implementation, or both." Otherwise, you're asking an impossible thing. You have to assume there will be some trade-off.

Comment: Yes, I am open to change the signature, but not in a way that changes the client/test code. As I said in the question: `the client/test code must not change`. So the trade-off for me was, in the end, accepting to override the `process` method. It's terrible for maintenance, but the client code being clean is more important for me. Consider I want to add `x` and `y`. Then `sum = x.add(y)` is best, while `sum = x.add(x,y)` is very strange, and `sum = U.add(x,y)` is not very OOP, right?

Comment: @marc I agree with you in that it's not very OOP, however, overriding 570 methods just for typing instead of creating 30 static methods and invoking them from the client is incredibly tedious, to say the least. Using U.add(x,y) is not so terrible. Before Java 8, that was the "functional" programming style in Java, i.e. Google Guava library is almost all based on static methods that receive callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

An instance of class `A` will always return an instance of `A` from `process`. This is because the call to `getClass()` will always return `A` (since that is what the object is an instance of. Likewise, an instance of class `B` will always return an object of type `B` because `getClass` will return `B`.

The reason you are getting runtime errors instead of compile time errors is because you are ignoring the generic information in `Class` when creating a new instance to return.

Ultimately the problem is that your api advertises that the type of object returned can be controlled by the caller, when in fact it is determined by the type of object the method is called on.

Comment: Yes Brett. I want those errors. My question is that I want them to be compile time errors. If I write `b.process(...)` the compiler knows that the type of `b` is `B`. So the compiler could, in principle, tell me that `C result = b.process(c)` is wrong at compile time.

Comment: The compiler cannot tell that `C result = b.process(c)` is wrong at compile time. The `process` method signature indicates that is correct. The problem is either the method signature or the implementation (or some combination of the 2).

Comment: Yes, I want to modify the signature, the implementation, or both.

Answer (score 0):

Would this suffice?  The only changes I made in your unit test are the following:

1. Renamed variables to not collide
2. Typed variables `a`, `b`, `c` as `AImpl`, `BImpl`, `CImpl` respectively.  No generic parameters, but not pure interfaces either.

Voici the code:

```
interface Processor< T extends Processor< ? extends T > > {
    T process( Processor< ? > p );
}
abstract class AbstractProcessor< T extends AbstractProcessor< ? extends T > > implements Processor< T > {
    public T process( Processor< ? > a ) {
        // ... actual processing
        return reproduce();
    }
    abstract T reproduce();
}

interface A {}
interface B extends A {}
interface C extends B {}

class AImpl extends AbstractProcessor< AImpl > implements A {
    AImpl reproduce() { return new AImpl(); }
}
class BImpl extends AbstractProcessor< BImpl > implements B {
    BImpl reproduce() { return new BImpl(); }
}
class CImpl extends AbstractProcessor< CImpl > implements C {
    CImpl reproduce() { return new CImpl(); }
}

@org.junit.Test
public void test()
{
    AImpl a = new AImpl();
    BImpl b = new BImpl();
    CImpl c = new CImpl();

    // Returns type A:

    A resultAAA = a.process(a); // Works.
    A resultAAB = a.process(b); // Works.
    A resultAAC = a.process(c); // Works.

    B resultBAA = a.process(a); // Type error.
    B resultBAB = a.process(b); // Type error.
    B resultBAC = a.process(c); // Type error.

    C resultCAA = a.process(a); // Type error.
    C resultCAB = a.process(b); // Type error.
    C resultCAC = a.process(c); // Type error.

    // Returns type B:

    A resultABA = b.process(a); // Works.
    A resultABB = b.process(b); // Works.
    A resultABC = b.process(c); // Works.

    B resultBBA = b.process(a); // Works.
    B resultBBB = b.process(b); // Works.
    B resultBBC = b.process(c); // Works.

    C resultCBA = b.process(a); // Type error.
    C resultCBB = b.process(b); // Type error.
    C resultCBC = b.process(c); // Type error.

    // Returns type C:

    A resultACA = c.process(a); // Works.
    A resultACB = c.process(b); // Works.
    A resultACC = c.process(c); // Works.

    B resultBCA = c.process(a); // Works.
    B resultBCB = c.process(b); // Works.
    B resultBCC = c.process(c); // Works.

    C resultCCA = c.process(a); // Works.
    C resultCCB = c.process(b); // Works.
    C resultCCC = c.process(c); // Works.
}
```

Comment: If `A resultAAA = a.process(a)` then I should be able to write `A newResult = resultAAA.process(a)`. However this is not possible because interface `A` has no methods. The results will be reused for further processing.

Comment: The interfaces `A` `B` `C` are useless here except that at least they can be in an inheritance relationship.  `AImpl`, `BImpl`, and `CImpl` can't, for the reason I expressed in my comment above: they would be implementing `Processor< T >` in multiple ways, which Java refuses to allow because of type erasure.  You can chain together as many `process()` calls as you want, however.